# animations ios objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, core-animation

I have a global variable p.
I have a function that draws (or redraws) my complex UIView objects depending on the value of this global variable.
When I increase p my uiview objects needs to be redrawed. I need this be done using animation.

```
double pInitialValue=0.5;
double pNewValue=1.0;

//somewhere before animation we must call [self redraw] to draw our view with p=pInitialValue;

//then, when we call animate function.
//we change p to pNewValue
//and every step must be redrawed using [self redraw]

p=pNewValue; //using animation p must slowly grow from pInitialValue to pNewValue
[self redraw]; //and ofcourse user must see every step of animation so we need to call redraw function
```

for example I need an animation with duration 4.
That means that during this 4 seconds my p must grow from pInitialValue to pNewValue and in  every step my redraw function must be called

Help me, please. How can it be done?

Comment: Did you hear about the standard UIView Animations? They do almost everything with just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a timer to increase your `p` value. Do that like this: have an instance variable in your class defined like

```
NSTimer *timer;
```

After that just before you want your animation to happen do:

```
CGFloat timerInterval = 1 / 30; // This means 30 frames per second. Change this as you want.
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timerInterval target:self selector:@selector(increaseP) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Than have a method called `increaseP`like this:

```
- (void)increaseP
{
    if (p < maxPValue) {
        // Increase p here and redraw your things
    }
    else {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any question and if this works for you.

Comment: Everything works fine. But this animates my view's rotation linear. How can it be done animating it like UIViewAnimatinCurveEaseIn ?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Unfortunately I don't think I can help you with that as I have no good idea of how you can increase the pValue in a non-linear way. You should ask another question to be able to get help from someone else. Cheers!